# NuGet error on creating MVC4 Project in VS 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I tried to create a MVC4 empty project in VisualStudio 2012 Ultimate, but I got this error:

> "Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 'NuGet.VisualStudio.Interop, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.".

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I believe you do not have NuGet Package Manager extension installed.

If not, you can click **TOOLS** -> **Extensions and Updates...** -> **Online**, select **NuGet Package Manager**, and click **Download**:

[image]

After it downloads, you will be prompted for administrative elevation, and then to restart Visual Studio.

**Tested in:** Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 (Version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3)

**UPDATE**: I've just came across this problem in Visual Studio 2012. So despite some comments here, it is not necessarily installed by default.

Comment: Nuget is install by default in Visual Studio 2012

Comment: @MystereMan Not in Express it seems :-(

Comment: @drozzy - Yes, VS 2012 Web has NuGet installed by default.  Other versions do not, but Web does.  Besides, the question was asking about Ultimate.

Comment: Still an issue in VS 2013.

Comment: +1 this has solved the issue for me too. @MystereMan: I installed VS2012 Ultimate from ISO, followed by Update 4 and Nuget was not installed. Not knowing that was the cause, coming across this answer and installing Nuget Package Manager solved the issue. It seems that Nuget PM is **not** installed by default across all versions after all.

Comment: Not sure why... but my install of VS2012 Ultimate didn't add NuGet.  Manually added it, and everything is happy now.  Thanks!

Comment: Works also in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Solved my problem and I have visual studio ultimate

Answer (score 20):

i) Open Visual Studio > Tools > Extensions and Updates > select 'NuGet Package Manager' and uninstall it.(if it's not installed go to step 2)

ii) Open this url 'http://nuget.org' and you will see an 'Install NuGet' link , download it(NuGet.Tools.vsix) and install it on your Visual Studio .

iii) Close and Re-open the Visual Studio and i believe you will never see that error Dialog again just like me ;-)

Comment: I didn't even have the 'Extensions and Updates' option listed. Not sure HOW I ever even got to such a place where I had VS 2012 Ultimate Installed but no NuGet. Huh? 
At any rate, installing nuget (as per Mahdi's instructions) was the FIX.

Comment: That's it.  Had to search for "NuGet Package Manager" in online extensions first though.

Answer (score 5):

Same issue.

```
"Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 
'NuGet.VisualStudio.Interop .... "
when creating a new Web Role project in VS 2012.
```

Selecting:

- TOOLS
- Extensions and Updates
- Online
- Select NuGet Package Manager
- Click Download
- i could see NuGet was installed already
- I removed it
- installed it again
- restarted VS

Resolved.

Thanks for the information above + 1.
Scott

Answer (score 2):

you might want to search and check the dll exists under \Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ (it would be in a folder under extensions with other nuget binaries). If it doesn't exist you can try uninstalling and re-installing nuget.
to uninstall: tools->extensions and updates -> installed (on the left pane)-> nuget package manager
to install: tools->extensions and updates -> online->visualstudio gallery -> nuget package manager

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio and go to Tools- > Open Extension Manager or Extension and Updates - > Uninstall Nuget Package Manager -> Then Download Nuget Manager again from Online Gallery and then restart visual studio and you wont see the error message.